# Return JavaScript from Controller As Content or JavaScriptResult

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference if I return some JavaScript from my MVC controller as either

**Content**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyEndPoint([System.Web.Http.FromBody] string result)
    {
       string jsResponse = "<script>";

        if(result == "SUCCESS")
        {
            jsResponse = "SubmitOrder();";
        }
        else
        {
            jsResponse = "alert('Problem processing your order, please try again')";
        }
        jsResponse += "</script>";
        return Content(jsResponse);
    }
```

**JavaScriptResult**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyEndPoint([System.Web.Http.FromBody] string result)
    {
       string jsResponse = "<script>";

        if(result == "SUCCESS")
        {
            jsResponse = "SubmitOrder();";
        }
        else
        {
            jsResponse = "alert('Problem processing your order, please try again')";
        }
        jsResponse += "</script>";
        return JavaScript(jsResponse);
    }
```

Also, are there any security precautions I need to be aware of when return JavaScript from a MVC controller method/call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, a `JavaScriptResult` returns the response as `application/javascript` MIME type vs the default `text/html` that using `Content()` returns. Because of that, the `JavaScriptResult` won't do what it looks like you're attempting (executing the JS). The browser doesn't just execute anything sent to in in a response. Since `Content()` is actually sending HTML, the browser can render it, in this case executing the script in the script tag. I haven't seen `JavaScriptResult` used often, but where I have, it's usually used to serve scripts dynamically. For example:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SomeAction() {
    ...
    return JavaScript("script content");
}
```

**View**

```
<script src="MyController/SomeAction">
```

Regarding security, you'll obviously want to avoid executing anything that's been passed in from the user, whether that be from the request body, query string, etc. I'd wager, however it being a bit of a design issue and you couple your front end and back end, so regardless, it's probably best to use sparingly.